# Moq - Mock Generic Repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a Generic repository and are trying to cast the .Returns to a Expression but it refuse... My code is following:

```
public RepositoryTest()
{
    IList<MockObjectSet> mocks = new List<MockObjectSet>()
    {
        new MockObjectSet { FirstName = "Beta", LastName = "Alpha", Mobile = 12345678 },
        new MockObjectSet { FirstName = "Alpha", LastName = "Beta", Mobile = 87654321 }
    };

    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<MockObjectSet>>();

    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<MockObjectSet, bool>>>()))
        .Returns((Expression<Func<MockObjectSet, bool>> predicate) => mocks.Where(predicate).ToList());

}
```

It just say

`Delegate System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<expWEBCRM.Tests.Repositories.MockObjectSet>> does not take 1 arguments`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the type parameters of the `Returns` overload like so:

```
mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<MockObjectSet, bool>>>()))
        .Returns<Expression<Func<MockObjectSet, bool>>>(predicate => mocks.Where(predicate).ToList());
```

**EDIT** The repository takes an expression and uses it on a `IQueryable`. The mock data source is actually an `IEnumerable`. The difference in the LINQ interface is one takes a lambda, the one an expression:

```
IQueryable<T>.Where(Expression<Func<T,bool>>);
IEnumerable<T>.Where(Func<T,bool>);
```

What happens in this scenario is trying to call `IEnumerable.Where` with `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`. The easiest way to fix this is to have the source collection as `IQueryable`:

```
public RepositoryTest()
{
    IQueryable<MockObjectSet> mocks = new List<MockObjectSet>()
    {
        new MockObjectSet { FirstName = "Beta", LastName = "Alpha", Mobile = 12345678 },
        new MockObjectSet { FirstName = "Alpha", LastName = "Beta", Mobile = 87654321 }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<MockObjectSet>>();

    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<MockObjectSet, bool>>>()))
        .Returns<Expression<Func<MockObjectSet, bool>>>(predicate => mocks.Where(predicate).ToList());

}
```

Comment: Perfect! But now another error shows up: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<expWEBCRM.Tests.Repositories.MockObjectSet>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments